# .text() jquery inline while forming the div

Tags: jquery, html, text, xss

$('#box').text("hello"); will display as text.How do i use it when im forming a div in a loop?

```
for(i=0;i,3;i++) {
        description+ = "<div id="box">+text[i]+</div>";
}
```

how can i specify inline that the text should not execute as a script.

Edit : forgot the +

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
text = [1,2,3];
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        description+ = '<div id="box">' + text[i] + '</div>"';
}
```

Edit: Escaping script tag, `you need to change </script> to <\/script>`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KEJdU/1/)**

```
text = ['<script>alert("Hi");<\/script>','<script>alert("Hi");<\/script>','<script>alert("Hi");<\/script>'];
description ="";

for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        description += '<div id="box">' + text[i] + '</div>"';
}
```

Comment: No even then suppose text[i] is <script>alert("Hi");</script> it will get executed. I want it to be displayed as text without allowing it to get executed

Comment: Updated my answer for not executing script with live demo.

Comment: I need a more generic answer. The text neednt necessarily be a script tag.

Comment: Well if its not script tag then will it be executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMP tag to prevent execution of script.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        description+ = '<div id="box"><xmp>' + text[i] + '</xmp></div>';
}
```